# Jade_Mixin is not a function, Windows environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, pug

I've been having an error exclusively in a Windows (8) environment with Jade; Jade will not compile because it does not recognize my mixin. The mixin is being called as such:

+MyMixin(true)

I keep getting the error that my mixin is not a function. I don't get this error in a Mac environment with the same exact code and file structure, which is why I'm confused. Jade is the latest version.

---

**Update**:
Here is the error message I get in the windows command line (terminal). I've changed the code a bit for confidentiality, however the syntax is unchanged.

```
[10:59:04] gulp-notify: [Gulp Error] Check your terminal
TypeError in plugin 'gulp-jade'
Message:
    C:\Users\Me\project_path\_jade_file.jade:25
    23|         -some code
    24|         -some code
  > 25|         +MyMixin
    26| // commented out
    27| more.code
    28|         -some more code

jade_mixins.MyMixin is not a function
Details:
    path: C:\Users\Me\project_path\_jade_file.jade:25
```

Comment: Can you provide full example?

Comment: Updated with terminal error.

Comment: I'm flagging to close - it's been two years and this Question doesn't have a MCVE or a reproducible problem.